# List undefined references from object file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

So I'm building a bunch of modules with g++. I hit some of the source files with -c to produce the .o object files. I then at some points combine object files using the -r flag for ld to produce even more .o files. Somewhere in the process, a function is not getting included. So what I'm trying to do is find a quick tool that looks at a .o file and tells what references are currently undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the `nm` command on Linux/Unix. In the output, "U" means the symbol is undefined.

Also see: [Difference between nm and objdump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219845/difference-between-nm-and-objdump).

Answer (score 10):

On Linux you'd use `objdump -t` for that. Look for `*UND*` in its output.