# Find static library unresolved dependencies before linking executable

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

So let's say we have static library mylib.a, which contains compiled cpp files.

> file1.cpp:

```
int do_stuff();

int func_unres()
{
  int a = do_stuff();
  return a;
}
```

> file2.cpp:

```
int do_other_stuff();

int func_res()
{
  int a = do_other_stuff();
  return a;
}
```

> file3.cpp:

```
int do_other_stuff()
{
  return 42;
}
```

So, as we can see here, no file contains definition of `do_stuff` function.
Library created this way:

> g++ -c file1.cpp -o file1.o
>
> g++ -c file2.cpp -o file2.o
>
> g++ -c file3.cpp -o file3.o
>
> ar r mylib.a file1.o file2.o file3.o

Now we try to make some binary with this library. Simple example main file:

```
#include <iostream>

int func_res();

int main()
{
  std::cout << func_res() << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling:

> g++ main.cpp mylib.a -o my_bin

Everything works just fine.
Now consider case of main file like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int func_unres();

int main()
{
  std::cout << func_unres() << std::endl;
}
```

In this case binary won't link, cause `func_unres` requires function `do_stuff` to be defined.

Is there a way to find out that static library requires symbol which no object file in the library contains before linking it with executable, which uses such symbol?

> EDIT:
>   The question is not how to simple list such symbols, but to get an output with linker like error.
>   Like if i linked this library with executable using all of symbols it should contain.

Comment: `Is there a way to find out that static library requires symbol which no object file in the library contains before linking it with executable, which uses such symbol?` How would you know which symbols are used in the executable? Or are you interested in _all_ symbols that are not defined but used in a static library?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, i want to make sure that all symbols that library uses are defined in it's object files

Comment: So just list symbols with objdump that are undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List undefined references from object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580875/list-undefined-references-from-object-file)

Comment: @KamilCuk That's just too dumb solution for this if library is huge and contains thousands of symbols. What i want exactly is the output like if i linked a binary that uses all of the symbols library contains, so i will get an error if something is undefined

Comment: So list all undefined symbols from your library, create a C file that calls all these symbols, compile and link and you will get an error.

Comment: @KamilCuk Once again. If library is really huge it's too much of work. And if i have big project and decided that some functional can be a library, after i make this library and edited cmake of all my binaries in the project some of them compile and some don't cause of missing symbols. And i want something automated to find such symbols and give me error or two before compiling and linking giant project of tons of binaries

Comment: `it's too much of work` No, it's not, it's like `nm mylib.a | awk '$2 == "u" { print "void "$3"(void); "$3"();" }' > file.c; gcc file.c mylib.a`. `And i want something` so implement that, stackoverflow is not a free writing service. It seems that even `gcc -Wl,--whole-archive mylib.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive`  is enough to list all undefined symbols (and `main`).

Comment: I don't get it. Why is an error emitted by this hypothetical pre-link tool better than having it come from the linker?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i want exactly error from linker, but before linking an executable. So if that "hypothetical pre-link tool" could give such error, that would be awesome. Maybe there are some tools except looking at unresolved symbols manualy

Comment: @KamilCuk i never asked you to implement something for me. I just wonder if there any tools that output linker like error before linking executable

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: “Why is an error emitted by this hypothetical pre-link tool better than having it come from the linker?” Because the tool would tell you if **any** symbol used by the library is not defined, whereas linking would only tell you if a symbol used as a result of library object modules included by that executable is undefined. The latter might not occur with a particular executable, so it is insufficient to test that a library is complete before releasing it, unless the executable is known to contain a reference to at least one symbol in each object module of the library.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that as pointed in comments and in [How to force gcc to link an unused static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library), linker option `--whole-archive` is enough to force resolve all symbols and output linker error for all unresolved symbols in static library. So referring the question examples, compiling and linking this way first main file, which doesn't refer undefined symbol, will output linker error anyway:

> g++ main.cpp -Wl,--whole-archive mylib.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive

Linking fails despite main doesn't use `func_unres`:

> mylib.a(file1.o): In function func_unres(): file1.cpp:(.text+0x9):
>   undefined reference to do_stuff()

Second option `--no-whole-archive` is used so the rest of required libraries' symbols will not be force resolved like this.